# Why we use Bind method on onClick event

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React.js .In the tutorial the author use onClick with bind , but at some places he do not use the bind with the onClick.
I can not get the difference between the two.

```
 <button onClick={this.handleAdd}>Add Item</button>
```

Comment: Can you post the other example of using the `bind` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might use `bind` in order to pass in a certain argument to the handler method.

For example:

```
render: function() {
    return _.map(list, function(item) {
        return <li onClick={this.clickItem.bind(this, item)}>{item.name}</li>;
    });
},
clickItem: function(item, event) {
    //do something with the clicked item
}
```

If you don't need to inject an argument, you don't need to `bind` since react always calls the handler method in the scope of the component - [although this is changing soon](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)

Comment: That is not the reason you use the `bind` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: Very true. But I think I posted this answer before `React.Component` existed (actually yeah, I reference the "coming change" in my answer).  Back then, you always used `React.createClass()`, which meant that `this.handleAdd` would always be bound to the component instance, and you would never use `bind` unless you had an argument to pass.  I guess you could override `this` if you wanted to, but that would've been really odd to do for a component's method.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for clarifying that :+1: